# how can I add multiple folding card cells in this flutter code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried this plugin [folding_cell](https://pub.dev/packages/folding_cell) for foldable card widgets. But I don't know how to add multiple cards If you know any solution please help me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:folding_cell/folding_cell.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(body: Material(child: FoldingCellSimpleDemo())))));

/// Example 1 folding cell inside [Container]
class FoldingCellSimpleDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  final _foldingCellKey = GlobalKey<SimpleFoldingCellState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: SimpleFoldingCell(
          key: _foldingCellKey,
          frontWidget: _buildFrontWidget(),
          innerTopWidget: _buildInnerTopWidget(),
          innerBottomWidget: _buildInnerBottomWidget(),
          cellSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 125),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          borderRadius: 10,
          onOpen: () => print('cell opened'),
          onClose: () => print('cell closed')),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFrontWidget() {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFFffcd3c),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("CARD",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
              child: Text(
                "Open",
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.indigoAccent,
              splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildInnerTopWidget() {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFFff9234),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text("TITLE",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)));
  }

  Widget _buildInnerBottomWidget() {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFFecf2f9),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => _foldingCellKey?.currentState?.toggleFold(),
          child: Text(
            "Close",
          ),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.indigoAccent,
          splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Example 2 folding cell inside [ListView]
class FoldingCellListViewDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SimpleFoldingCell(
                frontWidget: _buildFrontWidget(index),
                innerTopWidget: _buildInnerTopWidget(index),
                innerBottomWidget: _buildInnerBottomWidget(index),
                cellSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 125),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                borderRadius: 10,
                onOpen: () => print('$index cell opened'),
                onClose: () => print('$index cell closed'));
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFrontWidget(int index) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            color: Color(0xFFffcd3c),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("CARD - $index",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    SimpleFoldingCellState foldingCellState =
                    context.ancestorStateOfType(
                        TypeMatcher<SimpleFoldingCellState>());
                    foldingCellState?.toggleFold();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Open",
                  ),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                  splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                )
              ],
            ));
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInnerTopWidget(int index) {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFFff9234),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text("TITLE - $index",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)));
  }

  Widget _buildInnerBottomWidget(int index) {
    return Builder(builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        color: Color(0xFFecf2f9),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              SimpleFoldingCellState foldingCellState = context
                  .ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<SimpleFoldingCellState>());
              foldingCellState?.toggleFold();
            },
            child: Text(
              "Close",
            ),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.indigoAccent,
            splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

please visit this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faob-dev/folding_cell/master/screenshots/fc_demo2.gif) to see image [as stack overflow is  not allowing gifs]

Please help me if you have already tried this package to in your apps.

If you need more info then please comment thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List example is in your own piece of code too,
Just call **FoldingCellListViewDemo** in **main** method.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(body: Material(child: FoldingCellListViewDemo())))));
```

```
class FoldingCellListViewDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF2e282a),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SimpleFoldingCell(
                frontWidget: _buildFrontWidget(index),
                innerTopWidget: _buildInnerTopWidget(index),
                innerBottomWidget: _buildInnerBottomWidget(index),
                cellSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 125),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                borderRadius: 10,
                onOpen: () => print('$index cell opened'),
                onClose: () => print('$index cell closed'));
          }),
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Question: How to change the title and subtitle content?

Answer: Please check the working demo [here](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/94b3b2d2e129239f34b912ef202b6641)

Output

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.It is working now.But how can I change texts in card-1,card-2 add titles, and contents

Comment: @ramanraman I have created a gist for your need. Please check the code [Here](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/94b3b2d2e129239f34b912ef202b6641)